# Quando usar o "try catch" em aplicação com camadas?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, try-catch

Vamos supor que tenho minhas camadas

1. Controller
2. Business
3. Repository

sendo assim é necessário criar esse bloco nas 3 camadas ou criar apenas na *controller*?

Caso eu faça isso ela garante que todo código que for feito dentro dela a exceção será jogada até ela? Corre em algum momento o risco de perder o *stack trace*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro, depende do que está chamando de camada. Se são camadas de código dentro da mesma aplicação, sim, a exceção vai borbulhando até que alguém a capture, em último caso o .NET captura para você e faz alguma coisa (mostra o erro de forma padrão).

Exceção é uma mecanismo complicado, é um `goto` que você não sabe nem onde vai parar. Você não é obrigado a lidar com a falha (ao contrário do que muitos dizem sobre este mecanismo) e não sabe quem lidará com ela.

Se fizer certo não perde o *stack trace*, mas para isso é importante não ficar capturando para lançar a exceção de novo. O problema é que em códigos que abusam de exceção e usam como mecanismo de validação é comum fazer isso, especialmente em camadas, então sua tendência será capturar em uma camada para lançar outra coisa em outra camada.

Muitas vezes lançar exceções pode ser [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). É muito complicado fazer a exceção ser algo natural, um dos motivos para não usá-la para controle de fluxo, como parece ser o caso que está querendo fazer, até porque se elas fossem usadas para situações excepcionais provavelmente não estaria vivendo este dilema.

Sem uma análise profunda é complicado dar uma resposta definitiva sobre o problema, e mesmo soluções mais genéricas causam polêmica, já vi pessoas defendendo uma coisa ou outra.

Se usar certo a exceção não deve ir além da camada onde ela se origina, mais um motivo para não se preocupar com o *stack trace*. No repositório parece um local adequado para capturar alguns tipos de exceções bem específicas.

Na camada de negócios raramente deveria ter exceções porque ali você só terá validações, só terá coisas que você tem controle, o que falhar provavelmente é esperado, não é excepcional.

Mas sempre é possível fazer algo diferente. Se é o *controller* que monta o que será mostrado para o usuário, lá pode ser o local adequado para capturar uma exceção verdadeira. Há controvérsias quanto a isto, mas uma das vantagens da exceção é não ter que ficar repassando, você deixa estourar até chegar no local onde pode fazer algo útil, e na maioria das vezes é quando vai interagir com o usuário (ainda que o *controller* não seja o local de interação, é o último de código que rodará nesta camada da solução, o lado *backend*).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, sempre muito bom ler seus posts.

Answer (score 1):

1- Eu prefiro tratar os erros em uma camada mais superior tipo controller.

2- Você não vai perder o stacktrace no primeiro error que o try catch pegar ele vai tratar
e lançar a exception.

3-Quando usar ? você deve usar o try catch em partes da aplicação que você sabe que podem ocorrer erros digamos por influências externas como acesso a um banco de dados , manipulação de arquivos etc..

Comment: Foi o que imaginei Eduardo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)