# Setters em um array

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, getters-setters

Tenho um *array* de inteiros privado separado em uma classe (obs.: fiz assim para treinar o uso do `get` e do `set`) e outra classe que deve setar os valores nos endereços do *array*. Este é um exemplo reduzido do meu código para que vocês entendam melhor

```
//Classe com os numeros a serem utilizados
public class Numeros {

    private int[] numeros = new int[]{
                0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
}

//GUARDA A COMBINAÇÃO DE 5 DEZENAS
public class Dezenas {
    private int[] dezenas = new int[2];
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setDezenas(int... dezenas) {
        this.dezenas = dezenas;
    }

    public int[] getDezenas() {
        return this.dezenas;
   }}

//FAZ TODAS AS COMBINAÇÕES POSSÍVEIS
public class Gerador {

    private void gerador() {
        for (int numero : numeros) {

            dezenas[0] = numero;

            for (int numero1 : numeros) {
                dezenas[1] = numero1;
            }}}}
```

O código em uma única classe funciona, mas como estou treinando os modificadores de acesso quero descobrir como se faz. No caso do for em `dezenas[]` como iria setar o endereço usando o `set`? Da forma que está ai é de quando tudo fica em uma mesma classe.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. Entendi o que está tentando fazer, mas não a dúvida.

Comment: Maniero, no caso é como seria a sintaxe de um set onde vai setar o valor do endereço da memória no for, tipo lá está dezenas[1]. Preciso setar o valor de cada posição do array e não sei como fazer isso usando o set

Comment: A pergunta ainda está confusa sobre o que é isto, o comentário fala de uma coisa diferente da pergunta. Dei uma resposta veja se isto ajuda alguma coisa para tentar salvar a pergunta. Se não for possível apagarei a resposta e a pergunta infelizmente terá que ser fechada por ser incompreensível o que se deseja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem estiver com a mesma dúvida como eu a solução é bem simples.
Imagine que você crie um Array privado de nomes com 3 espaços;

```
private String[] name = new String[3];
```

Agora você quer acessá-lo em outra classe usando um Setter.
Crie o get normalmente, depois crie o setter da seguinte forma;

```
 public void setName (String name, int position){
     this.name[position] = name;
}
```

Agora para setar os valores vou utilizar um Scanner como exemplo:

```
System.out.println("Write the name: ");
    Scanner inName = new Scanner(System.in);
    colaborador.setNome(inName.next(),0);
```

Proto! Pra quem tinha dúvidas em como setar valores em um Array tá ai um exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

> Eu comecei responder e estou postando inicialmente para não perder a longa resposta, mas percebi que a pergunta está em condição ainda não respondível, apagarei se não for possível manter. Não considere essa resposta como correta ainda, melhorarei se for possível salvar a pergunta. Se não estiver muito curioso nem perca tempo em ler ainda, espero em breve poder deixar na versão definitiva

Quando vai treinar alguma coisa seria melhor pegar algo que faça sentido para fazer. Este exemplo faz muita coisa que não deve, provavelmente porque é só um exemplo, porém em desenvolvimento de software quando faz algo sem sentido você treina fazer algo sem sentido, você acostuma-se com isso.

A ideia de *getters* e *setters* é questionada. Não que não possa ser usada, mas quase sempre o uso é abusado. Pode ler mais aqui mesmo, tem uma [pergunta com vários *links*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

É ainda mais questionável quando ele recebe um *array*. Aliás *getters* e *setters* é uma abstração e fica estranho usar com um tipo tão concreto em algo abstrato. Dá a impressão que está criando a abstração sem saber porque. Não faça nada em programação sem saber porque está fazendo. Tudo precisa ser justificado e dizer "estou fazendo porque todo mundo está fazendo" não é um bom motivo. Então provavelmente deveria usar uma lista, preferencialmente uma interface de lista. Mas novamente, provavelmente nem deveria ter tudo isto no código.

Essa organização de classes também parece não fazer sentido. Classes devem existir para resolver um problema, devem ter um propósito, não devem ser quase aleatórias ou só porque achou bonito colocar assim. Inclusive na hora de dar nome para elas se eles não fizerem muito sentido já está errado.

Na forma como foi escrito esse código não diz porque tem essas classes. Se não pode justificar não faça nada disto. Eu estou com dificuldades para reescrevê-lo porque não sei o que é isto.

Note que o problema descrito no comentário nem tem a ver com *setter* conforme está na pergunta. E nem sei realmente se você entendeu que uma coisa não tem a ver com outra e que o *setter* não serve para isto.

Se vai mudar o *array* não pode usar o `for` de coleção de dados, ele serva para pegar dados, mas não para atribuir valores nele, o acesso a esses elementos é somente de leitura, então precisa usar o `for` bruto que varre manualmente toda coleção. Eu faria um código se eu tivesse entendido que combinações são estas que está tentando fazer, não vi como combinar de forma numérica.

Me parece que tudo isto deveria ser uma classe só. Talvez deveria ter um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), mas estou especulando. Não parece que deveria ter *setter*, dá a impressão que queria colocar um de qualquer jeito, mesmo sem sentido, mas pode ser só porque não está bem explicado. Me parece que o *getter* é uma [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). Uma ideia de código tentando combinar números, mas nem é isto, parece que quer sortear números, mas enfim, é alguma coisa:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numeros objeto = new Numeros();
        objeto.gerador();
        for (int item : objeto.getDezenas()) System.out.println(item);
    }
}

class Numeros {
    private int[] numeros = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private int[] dezenas = new int[100];
    public int[] getDezenas() {
        return this.dezenas;
   }
   public void gerador() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) dezenas[i * 10 + j] = i * 10 + j;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Q89Zrm). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/hketciyx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/FillData.java).

Neste exemplo em si nem deveria ter tudo isto, era para ser mais simples.

O resumo da estória: este exemplo desensina. Mas até achei útil porque podemos aprender com o erro, desde que seja criticando-o construtivamente.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo