# Criar e implementar Exceptions em PHP

Tags: php, exceção

Eu estou tentando aprender a lidar com `Exceptions` no PHP, mas não apenas usar o `Exception` padrão. Para resolver meu desafio, preciso criar duas Exceções e disparar elas em duas situações especificas. Segue o código:

#### Código principal onde as exceções serão chamadas

```
include("./testeA.php");
include("./exceptions.php");
$testeA = new TesteA(3);

try {
    $testeA->addName("steve rogers");
    $testeA->addName("Bruce banner");
    $testeA->addName("anthony Edward");
    echo $testeA->getNames();

} catch(LimitNameException $e){
    echo "Você não pode adicionar mais do que 
    {$testeA->getLimitNames()} nomes";
} catch(InvalidNameException $e){
    echo "Você deve inserir um nome válido";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Ocorreu um erro inesperado";
}
```

#### Classe `TesteA` (aqui talvez tenham alguns erros de lógica e falta coisas a implementar)

```
class TesteA
{
    public $nameArray = array();
    public $maxSize;

    function __constructor($maxSize){
        $this->maxSize = $maxSize;
    }


    public function addName($name){   
        array_push($this->nameArray, $name);      
    }


    public function getNames(){
        for($count= 0; $count<sizeof($this->nameArray); $count++){
            echo $count+1 .". ". $this->nameArray[$count] ."<br>";
        }
    }

    public function getLimitNames(){
        return $this->maxSize;
    }
}
```

#### Arquivo `exceptions` (aqui não tenho ideia de como utilizar as classes, dei uma lida na documentação do PHP e em outras perguntas semelhantes aqui no SOpt, porém não consegui compreender e aplicar de forma clara)

```
class LimitNameException extends Exception{

}
class  InvalidNameException extends Exception{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceção é algo sobrevalorizado. Elas são menos úteis do que as pessoas pensam e quase todo mundo usa errado. [Falo disso aos montes aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D). Em PHP, uma linguagem de *script*, faz menos sentido ainda, mas como as pessoas começaram usá-la como se ela fosse uma linguagem *enterprise*, vamos falar disto. Note que o primeiro *link* lá mostra outros mecanismos melhores para lidar com essa situação.

Você está já acima da média que sabe que `Exception` não é bom e só deve capturar em último caso (ainda que eu não colocaria aí onde colocou porque vai ter que repetir esse código em todo canto sem necessidade, curiosamente esse mecanismo existe justamente pra não ter que ficar repetindo, mas é o que as pessoas fazem).

Olhando os *links* acima verá que eu e muitas pessoas consideramos o uso de exceção para controle de fluxo, para indicar falha na regra de negócio, como algo muito errado, e é o que está fazendo. Pelo menos deixou a exceção mais específica. Ainda sobra o problema de querer usar algo porque está todo mundo usando, mesmo que elas não tenham ideia porque estão fazendo, ou sequer se é bom de verdade.

Quase sempre falar de exceção sem um contexto muito específico pode dar entendimento errado de como usar, mas vamos lá, faria assim:

```
public function addName($name) {
    if (len($name) > $this->getLimitNames()) throw new LimitNameException();
    if ($name == ????) throw new InvalidNameException();
    array_push($this->nameArray, $name);      
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Exception/ThrowValidation.php).

Portanto já que está usando equivocadamente a exceção para validação deve validar se está dentro da condição estabelecida (eu não tenho os requisitos então chutei um e só iniciei outro) e se não está, deve lançar a exceção.

Provavelmente deveria escrever alguma lógica extra dentro da exceção em si, e talvez receber algum argumento que dê mais informação sobre o que aconteceu, quem sabe por exemplo colocar mensagem de erro e até com o limite que deveria ter usado (inclusive porque a forma feita provavelmente já seria considerado [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101)), mas sem saber os requisitos não tenho como fazer muita coisa, estou só respondendo a pergunta específica.

Até nem é esse caso que é artificial demais, mas geralmente a exceção faz muito mais sentido no construtor já que ele não tem outra forma de comunicar um possível erro, o que faz alguns dizerem que não é uma boa construção para se usar.

Sem um domínio muito grande, quase todos os mecanismos, especialmente os mais complexos, devem ser evitados. Escrever código certo é bem mais complicado que parece, mas o que mais importa é entender onde se quer chegar, depois entender porque existe cada mecanismo ou técnica, para só usar o que realmente atende a necessidade sem causar outros problemas. Usar o mecanismo é a parte fácil, entender todo processo que o envolve é mais complicado.

Comment: Se alguém puder me falar oque está errado na resposta eu agradeço e a comunidade sairá ganhando.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, inclusive já tinha lido algumas das suas respostas sobre exception aqui no SOpt! O problema é que nesse caso sou obrigado a utilizar exception pois é uma prova de que, no minimo, entendo sobre e sei aplicar caso for preciso (independente de estar sendo usado de maneira correta ou não, como você disse)

Comment: O que você falou é inconsistente. Você tem que saber aplicar mesmo que não deva aplicar. Saber é aplicar é saber quando não aplicar. Me parece uma prova que não prova nada.