# Uso de length para contar strings concatenadas

Tags: javascript, string

Estou precisando resolver esse exercício mas ele está aparecendo com erro.

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome){
  return nome+ " " +sobrenome.lenght
}
```

no caso, os parâmetros tem que aparecer por exemplo `tamanhoNomeCompleto("Enzo", "Silva")` devolve 10, porém está aparecendo somente o nome e não está contanto.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

## TL; DR

É improvável que precise de um método que dê o tamanho de um nome completo sem criar este nome completo, então este método não faz sentido (estou especulando, não sei detalhes do problema), a solução seria ver qual é real necessidade e fazer isto, provavelmente seria criar o nome completo e este novo objeto tem exatamente o tamanho que deseja de forma natural e simples.

Se quiser insistir no erro de ter essa função o correto seria fazer isto:

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    return nome.length + sobrenome.length + 1;
}
console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto('Lila', 'Oliveira'))
```

## Outras respostas

As respostas atuais funcionam, mas não estão "certas", por uma razão básica, elas alocam memória sem necessidade só para dar uma informação puramente matemática. Isso pode não ser um problema na maioria das aplicações, pode sequer ser perceptível, mas para que fazer algo bastante custoso que coloca pressão no *garbage collector* podendo gerar pausas inesperadas para ganho zero? Certo é fazer o melhor que pode, não só dar o resultado certo.

A ideia do LeAndrade parece boa (apesar de no detalhe dar um resultado errado) porque você provavelmente terá que ter o nome completo, então faria mais sentido retornar um objeto novo criado com o nome completo, e aí a alocação não é desnecessária. Acontece que o problema da pergunta não fala nisso, então é uma especulação, uma boa, mas ainda não é o problema apresentado, mas eu nem quero me apegar a isto.

O problema é que uma função chamada `tamanhoNomeCompleto()` resulta em algo que não é o tamanho do nome completo, também faz isto, mas não só, é um *array* ou um objeto que tem isso e mais alguma coisa. Esta forma viola o princípio da [responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101), não que eventualmente esse princípio não deva ser violado, mas pelo menos deveria trocar o nome do método.

Porém se fizer isso, o método perde muito o sentido, e aí talvez a pergunta já conceitou errado. Se precisa do nome completo em algum momento, e acho que precisa (posso estar enganado), por que não cria logo? Aí achar o tamanho dele fica mais simples que criar uma função para isto e o problema da pergunta não existe.

Essa função deveria ser trocada por uma que gera o nome completo, e depois basta pegar o `length` (note que na pergunta está escrito errado, todo mundo erra, eu faço direto) desse nome. A função pode, ou não, ser interessante porque a operação se torna [canônica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), se precisar, mais curta de chamar, e evita algum possível erro se expor o mecanismo de concatenar de forma direta.

Se for fazer a ideia do LeAndrade (de forma geral eu não acho uma boa solução, poderia ser útil se eu entender o problema exato, com bom senso eu poderia adotar em algum caso) poderia ser isso:

```js
function nomeCompletoETamanho(nome, sobrenome) {
  return {
    tamanho: nome.length + sobrenome.length + 1, 
    nomeCompleto: nome + ' ' + sobrenome
  }
}
var nomeETamanho = nomeCompletoETamanho('Lila', 'Oliveira');
console.log(nomeETamanho.nomeCompleto);
console.log(nomeETamanho.tamanho);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/LengthConcat.js).

Um usuário em um chat indicou que poderia criar uma variável com o nome completo e retorná-la além de retornar o tamanho dela, aumenta uma linha mas evitaria a aritmética usada aí porque é justamente o que eu falei acima, cria o objeto e pega seu tamanho.

No código dele não pega o tamanho, só manda imprimir o resultado da função, que é um objeto ou *array*, se for pegar o conteúdo, compare o meu código com o dele:

```
nome.length
nomeCompletoETamanho.tamanho
```

Pra ficar legível tive que dar um nome significativo para a variável e ficou até redundante, porque é difícil dar nome para um objeto que tem coisas que não tem [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). A coesão é tão ruim que o segundo membro tem a mesma informação presente no primeiro membro, o tamanho já está no `nomeCompleto`.

Se fizer com *array* aí a legibilidade vai pro saco de vez então pode ficar mais curto, o meu e o dele:

```
nome.length
nome[0]
```

O que um `nome[0]` quer dizer? Você só sabe se for ver a implementação da função, é um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

Adoro essas perguntas porque dão a chance para mostrar na prática alguns conceitos que já respondi :)

Comment: Confesso que apesar da pergunta não dizer claramente que é para retornar o nome + sobrenome, pressupus isso pelo retorno dela que tem aspas separando, como sinal que queria não apenas retornar o tamanho das strings somadas, mas, como tbm o nome completo.

Comment: @LeAndrade achei a ideia geral "boa", tanto que a usei, mas aí precisaria fazer do jeito certo. Como eu disse eu acho que a **ideia geral** é boa, mas o jeito de fazer não, e seria aplicada em algum cenário específico. Uma coisa que eu não falei é que no fundo quando retorna o nome completo o tamanho o tamanho está junto implicitamente, note que eu usei `nomeETamanho.tamanho` para pegar o tamanho. Se só pegasse o nome completo eu faria só isso: `nome.length`, bem mais curto, né? Na sua resposta você nem pega os dados isoladamente, manda imprimir o objeto, o que nunca é o que a pessoa deseja.

Comment: Se fizer com o *array* fica mais curto, porém perde a semântica, faria algo assim `nome[0]` para pegar o tamanho. Olha que coisa complicada de ler, o que isso quer dizer? Prefiro escrever  `nome.length`, um tiquinho mais longo, porém bem legível. Concorda?

Comment: Sim claro, concordo, é meio complicado dar uma resposta exata quando a pergunta não está 100% clara. Apenas deixei uma forma de fazer para o código dela, com certeza se fosse outro cenário, com todas as informações necessárias, teria implementado de outra forma.

Comment: @LeAndrade eu achei até que ela está clara em certo sentido, porém não está se considerar que provavelmente é um problema XY. Eu duvido que precise de uma função que gere o tamanho do nome completo sem gerar o nome completo, e se o gerar, essa função não tem mais sentido de existir. Editei a resposta para dar mais detalhes disso.

Comment: Certo man, concordo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai conseguir dessa forma porque ele você precisa concatenar strings primeiro.
para você usar o length.

dessa forma funcionará seu código

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    return (nome + ' ' + sobrenome).length
}
console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto('Kusther', 'Developer'));
```

Comment: Lembrando que desta forma, não irá colocar o espaço em Branco entre o nome é o sobrenome, a não ser que seja passado nos parametros o sobrenome com espaço em branco primeiro. Mais é isso aí.

Comment: Pronto eu modifiquei.

Answer (score 1):

Fora o que o Artsher Developer exemplificou na resposta dele, o return do modo que fez retorna apenas o primeiro elemento encontrado, ou seja, o nome. Para você imprimir também o nome completo por exemplo, pode retornar um `objeto` **{ }** ou um `array` **[ ]**:

**Objeto:**

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
  return {
    tamanho: nome.length + sobrenome.length, 
    nome_completo: nome +' '+ sobrenome
  }
}

console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto('Enzo', 'Silva'))
```

**Array:**

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
  return [
    nome.length + sobrenome.length, 
    nome +' '+ sobrenome
  ]
}

console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto('Enzo', 'Silva'))
```