# Porque o comando this(6) dentro de um construtor inicializa o array da classe?

Tags: java, construtor, this

No código:

```
public class Lista{

        int [] a;
        int n;

        public Lista(){

                this(6);
        }

        public Lista(int i){

                this.a = new int [i];
                this.n = 0;
        }

        public static void main(String [] args){

                Lista l = new Lista();
                System.out.println("tamanho: " + l.a.length);

        }

}
```

Como o primeiro construtor `Lista()` identifica que o comando `this(6);` esta inicializando o array `int a[]` com o tamanho?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `this()` só está chamando o construtor, neste casos é um alias dele. É a forma de chamar este método especial chamado construtor. Como é possível ter um método normal existir na classe com o mesmo nome, no momento que está construindo ele não pode chamar pelo nome porque pode ser o construtor ou pode ser um método normal, por isso usa-se o nome `this()`. Então de uma certa forma podemos dizer que na verdade ele está chamando `Lista(6)` que é o outro construtor. E é neste outro construtor que está inicializando o *array* normalmente.

Então um construtor que tem uma assinatura, no caso sem parâmetros está chamando o outro construtor que aceita um parâmetro com o tamanho. Se você chamar o construtor sem parâmetros que é dito formalmente pela linguagem de **construtor padrão** ele assume um valor para você, no caso é 6.

Obviamente que esse segundo construtor não está só inicializando o *array*, o outro campo também, mas não tem porque deixar ele ser configurado pelo programador fora da classe, pelo que dá para perceber.

Para um exercício não é um problema, mas frequentemente esse método `main()` dentro dessa classe não é adequado, ele deveria estar em classe própria, isso fica como um ruído.

Seu código tem um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) (expõe o *array* pra fora) e não é considerado adequado, ainda que funcione, pesquise mais sobre o assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Porque a expressão `this(6)` invocará o método construtor que recebe um inteiro como parâmetro, pois é o tipo de parâmetro que você está passando. Por sorte esse método está definido logo abaixo:

```java
public Lista(int i){
    this.a = new int [i];
    this.n = 0;
}
```

E ele é responsável por inicializar a lista `a` com o valor de `i`, que é o parâmetro recebido, neste caso o 6.

Answer (score 2):

Porque `Lista l = new Lista()` se refere a chamada do construtor `Lista()`.

Dentro deste construtor, há o construtor `Lista(int i)` que está sendo chamado da seguinte forma

`this(6)`

Quando o segundo construtor é chamado, ocorre a inicialização do array

```
this.a = new int [i]
```