# O que pode ser feito para melhorar este código?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, solid

```
class Curso {
    public List<Disciplina> disciplinas;
}

class Aluno {
    public List<Disciplina> obrigatorias;
    public List<Disciplina> optativas;


    public matricula(){
        ...
    }
}

class Disciplina {
    List<Curso> pertencentes;

    public Disciplina(Curso curso) {
        this.pertence = curso;  
    }

    public getCurso(){
        return this.curso;
    }

    public setCurso(Curso curso){
        this.curso = curso;
    }
}
```

Meu professor de OO me passou essas classes pra eu analisar. Preciso achar o máximo de erro ou más práticas. pelo oque consegui ver tá tudo certo, mas queria saber de vocês há algo de errado no código? Ele mencionou sobre ter baixo acoplamento e sobre responsabilidades, não entendi muito bem.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

É muito complicado falar em boas práticas, tem muita opinião sobre isto. Também não dá para falar muito sem saber os requisitos, o caso concreto. Não existe boa prática em caso abstrato, só é uma prática boa se aplicar dentro do que precisa. Exemplos artificiais não servem para ensinar boas práticas, serve apenas para ensinar receita de bolo que as pessoas aplicarão de forma equivocada em casos reais.

Um exemplo que muita gente vai dizer que é boa prática é criar os *getters* e *setters* que criou. Isto é má prática. Sabe por que? Porque fez sem entender porque. Poderia até estar certo, como eu disse antes, depende do caso concreto, mas como fez porque alguém fez antes e disse que é bom, já é uma má prática. Pode começar estudar mais o assunto em [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

Não tem um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), quase sempre, mas não sempre, é uma boa prática ter um. E em boa parte das vezes o *setter* é inadequado.

Tem certeza que é adequado manter os campos que são listas como públicos ou internos ao pacote como fez? Tanto declarado assim explicitamente como implicitamente. Isso é [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). E se for mais adequado usar de um outro jeito mais pra frente? Pode ler também [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Não sei se `Aluno` deveria ter um método chamado `matricula()`. Isso pode ser um acoplamento indevido, mas novamente, sem requisito não tem como saber. Veja mais em [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Também pode ser sobre ter responsabilidade indevida, veja [O que é e como se usa o SRP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101).

Nem dá para ir muito além porque o código está pela metade, não usa o *array* criado, usa alguns campos ([e não atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) como as pessoas chamam) que não foram declarados na classe.

Programar orientado a objeto é difícil e sem requisitos claros é impossível até para os mais experientes. Mesmo com tudo isto nem sempre existem respostas definitivas e é ingênuo achar isto e pode virar cagação de regra :)