# O que exatamente é "Clean Architecture" (Arquitetura Limpa)? Como e onde usar?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-de-software, organização-de-projeto

Já vi diversas vezes em respostas e em outras páginas o termo *Clean Architecture*. O que exatamente é isso? Como foi criado? Onde e como deve ser usado? Há alternativas ou contraindicações ao seu uso?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O termo foi criado pelo Uncle Bob e a informação canônica sobre isto está na [página dele](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

É uma técnica, que pode ter sua efetividade, para explicar melhor algo já existente, e claro, vender livros e cursos, já que parece algo novo. Não que isso seja de todo errado, mas é bom ter claro que não é algo novo. No fundo é só a boa e velha **separação de responsabilidades**, que é algo bom se aplicado certo. E isso demanda experiência.

Sendo que o gráfico dá uma boa indicação:

[image: Arquitetura limpa]

Isso mostra que não é muito diferente de fazer camadas diferentes e com definições claras do que cada uma faz.

O livro afirma que não precisa ser exatamente essas camadas, pode ter mais ou menos delas. Ainda bem que tem certa abertura. Alguns dizem que só deveria ter o domínio e a infraestrutura (negócio e aplicação).

A ideia é que o que está mais para dentro dos círculos não deve conhecer os detalhes de implementação do que está mais pra fora.

Não precisava ser círculos, podia ser uma pilha (algo mais fácil de entender).

[image: Mostrando em forma de cônica]

Portanto:

- as entidades não devem saber
- como elas serão usadas, que não deve saber
- como serão processadas para contato com mundo externo, que não devem saber
- como deve ser o DB, a UI e a plataforma.

E eu concordo com isso, não se deixe levar pelas críticas que farei.

#### Nem tudo é tão limpo

<sub>Aqui começo uma análise crítica porque de forma simples está acima, e para entender com profundidade é melhor estudar profundamente, não é possível aprofundar em uma resposta aqui.</sub>

Um dos problemas é que as mudanças frequentes ocorrem em cima (*inner circle*) e não embaixo (*outer circle*).

Notou que o contrário não é verdadeiro? Porque é até bem difícil fazer, ainda mais se for fazer nas duas direções, e o contrário seria mais vantajoso para a manutenção de sistemas.

Percebeu que se mudar uma entidade terá que mudar todas as outras camadas? E isso acontece muito, a mudança de infraestrutura muda pouco.

Eu tenho tentado há anos ou décadas achar uma forma de facilitar as mudanças que ocorrem muito, com algum grau de sucesso, mas não tive tantas oportunidade de testar, e para isso faço muita coisa que vai contra o que todo mundo costuma pregar, mas dá um resultado absurdamente maior que o da *clean architecture*.

Se feito certo a tal arquitetura limpa pode ser bom para seu sistema, principalmente se puder pagar pela complexidade adicional que isso gera. No mundo ideal tudo deve ser assim mesmo.

Até onde entendo ela prega o uso de objetos anêmicos, que vai contra outras filosofias. Não vou entrar no mérito quem está certo porque obviamente ambos estão para cada caso específico, o problema é ser dogmático.

Tem muito discurso na metodologia que não se sustenta na prática, ainda que seria legal se sustentasse. O livro é vago em pontos que podem ser contestados.

#### Independência

Ele bate em alguns pontos:

- Independência de *frameworks* - geralmente isso complica muito o desenvolvimento e quase sempre não precisa, e se precisa será inefetivo, até porque a pessoa nunca consegue prever o futuro, você não troca fácil um *framework* sem mudar várias filosofias do sistema e sem muito trabalho. Além do que, para não [vazar abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) fará várias coisas bem ruins, ficará ineficiente, e ainda adotará o tal do *mínimo denominador comum* que faz você não aproveitar tudo de bom do *framework* que está usando. Se você acredita que dá para fazer tudo ficar ótimo, eu sei que é inexperiente, mesmo que faça isso há 30 anos.
- Testável - Algo bom, mas muitas pessoas complicam o sistema real só para poder testar. Dá para fazer isso de forma limpa, mas quase tudo o que se ensina sobre testes por aí não ajuda muito isso e complica a arquitetura (não que tudo fique complicado).
- Independente de UI - Não é diferente do primeiro, o que mostra como isso foi mal pensado, e é uma coisa boa, até certo ponto, só não vale para qualquer caso. Na prática poucos fazem isso e só ter essa independência pode não ser suficiente. Dependendo em que parte faz essa abstração pode ser ruim como eu já disse no primeiro item, só é interessante quando a UI já é naturalmente desacoplada (client-server), o que hoje até é comum, mas como algumas UIs estão acopladas com o último item (o azul e o verde do círculo) e você não tem controle sobre isso, é um problema (web, cof cof).
- Independente de banco de dados - é igual ao primeiro item e isso acontece muito sem necessidade, caindo nos problemas que citei inicialmente. Isso vale inclusive para uso de ORM (e se seguir o que foi dito você abstrai o DB e o ORM, terrível, mas tem muita gente, que é referência, pregando isso). Você não vai trocar o banco de dados e principalmente não vai mudar o modelo do banco de dados sem afetar uma boa parte da aplicação fundamentalmente.

  Eu acho útil em caso de você ter um produto "de prateleira" que precisa atender todo mundo, mas entenda que será um produto menos eficiente do que um feito *in house*, o que é um contrassenso porque um produto deveria ser sempre melhor. A não ser que faça realmente soluções completamente diferentes, o que vai custar bem mais caro, mas é a solução mais correta. As soluções *one fit all* sempre cobram preço depois (não importa qual seja esse preço).

  A interface com o banco de dados é sempre bem específica, ainda mais quando troca de modelo, e o próprio modelo você casa com ela ou usa o DB de forma muito ruim, o que faz com que as pessoas comecem adotar várias técnicas ruins para compensar os defeitos causados por isso.
- Independente de agentes externos - é só outra variação do primeiro item.

Se você entender que separar as coisas é bom, mas tornar tudo *plug and play* não, aí pode ser que entendeu o propósito das separações de responsabilidades.

Se concentre na separação das responsabilidades e não na independência das coisas. Separar para ser fácil dar manutenção real, para lidar com aquilo que ocorre "todo dia" e não com o que pode ocorrer uma vez na vida.

Uma troca de arquitetura sempre será traumática, não tem como escapar. Quando há uma mudança de arquitetura é comum mudar até de linguagem.

Acredite, eu sempre quis fazer tudo lindo como a metodologia prega, décadas antes dela existir, ou mesmo depois, e passei a vida tentando permitir essa troca de tecnologias de forma fácil assim, mas nunca cheguei nem perto de obter resultado bom. E fiz isso consultando muita gente muito boa. Dá pra facilitar, mas quanto mais se aprofunda mais caro vai ficando, ao ponto de praticamente reinventar tudo e cair no chamado [Second System Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect).

Ingênuos adotarão a metodologia sem entender tudo o que envolve isso e passará a vida toda defendendo o seu erro como algo certo, já vi isso ocorrer literalmente milhares de vezes.

Algumas pessoas vão notar que o DDD é só uma especialização ou pelo menos uma forma mais adiante disso. Assim como o artigo *linkado* mostra outros termos usados para indicar quase a mesma coisa.

#### Contraponto

O erro é como no passado que tudo era feito junto. Você entrava em uma função, lia o banco de dados, processava algo, apresentava para o usuário validava, processava, era tudo definido ali mesmo, e gravava no final.

#### Utilidade

Eu acho que deve estudar isso para ver mais detalhes como fazer, mas não deve limitar-se à essa técnica, não deve achar que ela é útil por si só, e não deve achar que ela deve ser usada por completo. Se você tiver pensamento crítico e com muitas fontes de informação então pode entender como ela lhe será útil. Porque no fundo é só uma forma mais detalhada e especializada de aprender o que eu já respondi em [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Eu acho que muitas vezes ela acaba criando complicações indevidas e por isso de "limpa" pode ter só o nome. Marketing é assim, dá nome bom para as pessoas entenderem algo que não é, tipo "aqui é mais barato", uma das 22 leis do marketing.

Pode ser só porque as pessoas não sabem fazer certo, mas esse é o problema dessas coisas, é bonito no papel, é uma ótima receita de bolo, mas na vida real é complicado fazer certo e ficar limpo de verdade. E quanto mais coisas você coloca no código tende a ser menos limpo, a não ser que você seja bom em fazer isso, o que aí faz com que não precise dessa receita de bolo.

A crítica é mais ao uso e não à técnica da arquitetura limpa. É como OOP, as pessoas fazem porque disseram que é bom, mas fazem errado, para elas o importante não é ser certo, só precisa dizer que está na moda.

## Onde usar

Então só deve usar onde:

- a equipe tem experiência
- esteja fazendo algo muito complexo
- tenha muita incerteza sobre a arquitetura, o que pode ser um problema a ser resolvido antes e eliminar a incerteza, em muitos cenários
- compensa pagar um preço alto para ter um pouco de facilidade em mudar o rumo da solução de forma radical

Isso não quer dizer que não deva usar pelo menos em parte. O aprendizado fará você codificar melhor em pontos específicos, adotando parcialmente.

## Aprender a fazer certo

E como treinar isso se custa tão caro? Alguéns (fiz questão do plural incomum porque serão vários casos) pagará a conta pelo seu aprendizado, e essa conta é bem cara. Quem sabe alguém terá uma vantagem no futuro com seu aprendizado.

Tem chance maior de dar certo depois que você fizer várias delas, precisar de fato mudar a arquitetura e aí ir aprendendo onde falhou para na próxima não errar mais no jeito de fazer a arquitetura tão abstrata assim de forma correta. Quer saber? Eu nunca vi alguém fazendo isso corretamente (sei que existe) na forma apresentada no livro, vi muita gente falando que fez, quando eu pude ver, estava errado. Quase sempre é um desperdício de recurso, na forma como as pessoas fazem.

É um paradoxo porque para fazer certo a pessoa precisa ser muito boa, e se ela for muito boa a pessoa faz a arquitetura certa para o problema. É parecido com microsserviço que é muito difícil fazer certo, se a pessoa tem capacidade para isso ela sabe fazer um monólito muito bom, e não precisa do microsserviço, mas a realidade é que quase todo mundo adota o microsserviço porque não conseguiu fazer um monólito bom. E CA provavelmente incentivará a pessoa a fazer microsserviço, dois problemas em um só.

Entenda que trocar todos componentes da arquitetura é muito complicado, e preparar para isso sem incorrer em vários problemas não costuma dar certo, e você acaba tendo o custo de fazer uma "arquitetura limpa" e de mudar várias partes do sistema comparando com a forma limpa de tudo isso.

Não faça isso em projetos pequenos, que terão pouca manutenção, ou que durarão pouco. Mas se adotar a metodologia tenha certeza que vai comprometer-se com o produto, que é o oposto do que vejo, a pessoa faz e depois abandona.

A primeira coisa que tem que pensar é se deve aplicar no caso concreto que for lidar. As pessoas aprendem a técnica e acham que devem aplicar em tudo, e raros os que aprendem quando dizer não.

Ficaria muito longo eu citar casos que as pessoas tiveram que mudar sim, mas foi tanto que toda estratégia foi jogada fora.

Não dá para falar sobre o como, [tem um livro inteiro sobre isso](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clean-architecture-a/9780134494272/). Gostei de um artigo com um bom resumo.

Pode ver um [projeto assim](https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga). Experimenta fazer isso no mundo real. Não falo só de ter muito penduricalho, mas também de aplicar bem. Não estou sendo irônico com o projeto, mas sim com o uso. E ele nem segue tanto assim a metodologia na parte de ser independente. Quero ver você trocar todos os componentes. Ainda é muito muito complicado, mesmo tendo pago um custo alto para fazer isso.

Eu relutei em postar isso porque alguém vai achar que é só copiar e isto e ficará fácil implementar.

## Conclusão

Não estou dizendo que a CA não ensina coisas boas, que não deva aprender e usar onde faça sentido pelo menos partes. Há um aprendizado aí, e só fazendo muitas vezes, ir melhorando é que te fará achar o nível certo.

Na teoria a ideia é muito boa, então na prática alguma utilidade tem, só estou dizendo que a **maioria** das pessoas colocam coisas que elas não precisam, não as beneficiam, geram custo, não geram valor, e passa a vida toda **achando** que está bom porque seguiu essa receita de bolo.

Eu adoraria ver isso funcionando tão corretamente quanto as pessoas que a propõe falam. Até funciona, mas tem muita coisa ruim que não é tão visível, por exemplo ninguém consegue demonstrar o quanto de custo aumentou e quanto reduziu.

Tenho notado que as pessoas a adotam sem nem piscar e isso acaba sendo uma forma de não precisar adotar a arquitetura certa porque "posso trocar para outra a hora que quiser ***"sem custo"***".

Eu gosto mais de *clean design* ou *right architecture*.

Regras de negócios mudam muito. Arquitetura não deveria mudar e se mudar é normal que tenha custo em fazer isso. Quase sempre que mude a pessoa está assinando atestado de incompetência (isso não é um insulto, é o termo para isso, eu sou incompetente em muitas coisas, fui em outras que hoje não sou mais porque depois de acreditar sem pensar a experiência me mostrou o caminho certo). Prepare seu software para as mudanças importantes. Esta técnica ajuda nisso, mas não exatamente da forma apresentada.

Esta técnica ajuda a gerenciar melhor a mudança da infraestrutura, mas não a mudança do domínio. Qual você acha mais importante?

Separação de responsabilidade é algo bom, deixar tudo intercambiável nem sempre.

Tente não casar com algumas coisas como o *framework*, meça os custos e depois me fala. De maneira alguma estou dizendo que não deve fazer isso, só entenda que tem custos, não adote achando que não tem.

Não sou o único que critica, veja comentário abaixo e procure pela internet. [Pode começar aqui](https://dev.to/bosepchuk/why-i-cant-recommend-clean-architecture-by-robert-c-martin-ofd). Ainda assim tem utilidade. Mas aparentemente algumas pessoas gostam incondicionalmente.

[Para aprender mais sobre arquitetura](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta. O Maniero já deixou um link para o blog Robert C. Martin. Deixo aqui o link para o livro: [Clean Architecture: A Craftsman's Guide to Software Structure and Design](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clean-architecture-a/9780134494272/), como o Maniero reforço que nem tudo que reluz é ouro. Eu li todos os livros da série "Clean", o Clean Architecture certamente não é meu favorito. Dito isso, o livro é uma introdução interessante a arquitetura hexagonal e um apanhado sobre "SOLID a nível de componentes". Tendo isso em mente, o livro não é ruim.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Melhorei um pouco mas ainda não estou satisfeito. É difícil responder aqui sobre isso, só pra resumir dá um capítulo de livro, eu até questionei se deveria responder em um chat, como ninguém falou nada eu respondi antes que sai uma resposta de uma parágrafo que não ajudará muito mais do que qualquer coisa que ache na internet. De fato tem umas coisas que explicam melhor como fazer essas coisas. Todos esses livros são bons se a pessoa tiver criticidade no que está lendo. Tem alguma outra sugestão de livro ou melhoria para a resposta?

Comment: E alguém não gostou. Vai ver a pessoa acha que é a coisa mais maravilhosa do mundo, mas como ela não quis dizer nada não ficaremos sabendo. Eu tive bastante trabalho em fazer tudo isso.