# Instanciando uma classe como sendo propriedade de outra classe

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade, inicialização

Tenho as classes:

```
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class Profissionais
    {
        public int idProfissional { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String CPF { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public String Sexo { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public int CodEspecialidade { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
        public String Endereco { get; set; }
        public String NumeroEnd { get; set; }
        public String CEP { get; set; }
        public String Bairro { get; set; }
        public String Cidade { get; set; }
        public String UF { get; set; }
        public String Telefone { get; set; }
        public String Celular { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public Especialidades especialidade { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

e

```
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class Especialidades
    {
        public int idEspecialidade { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public Boolean ativo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Como utilizo `Especialidades` dentro de `Profissionais`?

Verifiquem que já criei a propriedade do tipo `Especialidade`, mas quando vou adicionar um valor nela, instanciando o objeto `Profissionais` e diz que o objeto não está instanciado.

Abaixo como estou obtendo o valor:

```
 Profissionais profissional = new Profissionais();

 profissional.idProfissional = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["idProfissional"]);
 profissional.especialidade.idEspecialidade = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["codEspecialidade"]);
 **profissional.especialidade.descricao = Convert.ToString(dataReader["especialidade"]);**
 profissional.Nome = Convert.ToString(dataReader["nome"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta linha:

```
public Especialidades especialidade { get; private set; }
```

Claramente mostra que só pode escrever na propriedade (`set`) privativamente (`private`), portanto se deseja escrever nela publicamente tem que tirar esse atributo de visibilidade da propriedade e deixar com os outros.

Além disso não está criando um objeto para usar ali, se não desejar criar por conta própria pode fazer.

```
profissional.especialidade = new Especialidades();
```

Mas pode manter o campo privado se inicializar dentro da classe poderia fazer assim:

```
public Especialidades especialidade { get; private set; } = new Especialidades();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Instancing.cs).

Eu vejo outros problemas na concepção geral desses objetos, mas não é o foco da pergunta e já perdi as esperanças das pessoas fazerem certo. De qualquer forma vai "funcionar". Pode pesquisar sobre [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) e [abuso de *getter/setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101). Também [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

Comment: Quando vai setar o valor me dá isso:

Message "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."

Comment: Aí é outro problema e de algoritmo nesse código mostrado isso não ocorre. Eu respondi em cima do postado. Faça uma nova pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: Está chamando funções recursivamente?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você instancia um objeto `Profissionais` ele não cria automaticamente as instâncias dos campos, há vários jeitos de fazer isso:

## Com construtor

```cs
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class Profissionais
    {
        public int idProfissional { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String CPF { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public String Sexo { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public int CodEspecialidade { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
        public String Endereco { get; set; }
        public String NumeroEnd { get; set; }
        public String CEP { get; set; }
        public String Bairro { get; set; }
        public String Cidade { get; set; }
        public String UF { get; set; }
        public String Telefone { get; set; }
        public String Celular { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public Especialidades especialidade { get; private set; }
        public Profissionais()
        {
            especialidade = new Especialidades();
        }
    }
}
```

## Atribuíndo uma instância

```cs
Profissionais profissional = new Profissionais();
profissional.idProfissional = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["idProfissional"]);
profissional.especialidade = new Especialidades();
profissional.especialidade.idEspecialidade = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["codEspecialidade"]);
profissional.especialidade.descricao = Convert.ToString(dataReader["especialidade"]);
profissional.Nome = Convert.ToString(dataReader["nome"]);
```

---

Em suma, todo campo que é objeto do tipo `Referência` deve ser instanciado de algum modo. A propriedade está associada a um campo implícito.

Não existe um jeito certo de se fazer isso, mas com certeza existe um jeito mais eficiente.

Você deve considerar não expor objetos como propriedades (`get` e `set`) em um componente que vai publicar ou vender.