# O que é modelagem de dados (data modeling)?

Tags: terminologia, modelagem, engenharia-de-software

- O que é modelagem de dados (data modeling)?
- Em que contexto ela é utilizada?
- Em que momento do desenvolvimento ela deve começar a ser feita?
- Tem relação com orientação a objetos? Uma se opõe ou complementa a outra?

Comment: Usualmente está relacionada ao projeto do banco de dados. Deve ser uma das primeiras atividades do projeto. Não se pões à orientação a objetos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que é modelagem de dados (data modeling)?

Modelagem de dados é a definição de como as estruturas de dados de uma aplicação devem ser montadas. Então o desenvolvedor define quais são os dados que fazem sentido ter na aplicação, de que forma eles são organizados e detalhes relacionados de como esses dados são adotados na aplicação.

Alguns dos melhores profissionais na área colocam um peso muito maior nisso do que a criação de algoritmos, até porque se a modelagem é bem feita você pode aplicar o algoritmo que for necessário. Tendo todos os dados necessários e organizados de forma que faça sentido fica fácil aplicar operações, que é o fim da aplicação.

É aí que de fato você está desenhando o que sua aplicação será capaz de trabalhar e fazer. Não define como fazer, mas o que pode fazer.

Programar é criar modelos. Dados são o que os softwares devem manipular. Ponto.

A modelagem só ocorre com a coleta de requisitos. Boa parte do trabalho de desenho do modelo é saber o que o modelo deve fornecer, é entender o problema hoje e como ele poderá ser amanhã. Tem que conceituar muito bem.

Existem diversas técnicas que mandam você fazer exatamente isso. Vou citar uma que está na moda que é DDD. Embora ela não faça da forma mais simples possível. Inclusive incentiva um modelo um pouco complexo demais para meu gosto.

Não precisa de ferramentas para modelar algo. O código é suficiente para expressar o modelo. não quer dizer que elas não sejam úteis em certos cenários. Não precisa de um processo complexo, mas uma metodologia bem aplicada e alguma burocracia tem seu mérito nos contextos adequados. Modelar é muito simples e só precisa de cérebro e código em seguida, o que se faz de extra para modelar pode ajudar ou atrapalhar em cada caso ou para cada pessoa.

> Em que contexto ela é utilizada?

Pode usar em vários contextos.

Eu entendo que a literatura padrão encontrada fala mais no contexto do banco de dados, mas é um erro achar que modelar dados seja só isso. Talvez por isso os modelos de dados que não são de banco de dados sejam tão ruins. As pessoas não dão o mesmo valor.

Dentro da aplicação você tem dados, e precisa modelá-los, não pode ser aleatório. O que causa um caos é achar que só tabelas de banco de dados é que precisam de modelagem.

Onde tenha dados a serem manipulados você deve fazer modelagem. Quanto tempo vai gastar, que ferramentas adotar, o quanto deverá ser preciso e que nível de requisitos deve coletar, depende do que está trabalhando. Mas em qualquer caso fará um modelo, ainda que informalmente, estruturas definidas em código são modelos dos seus dados.

Inteligência artificial usa modelos de dados em sua essência. Não precisa de banco de dados.

> Em que momento do desenvolvimento ela deve começar a ser feita?

Em geral, o mais cedo possível, não faz muito sentido fazer depois que já precisou dos dados organizados.

> Tem relação com orientação a objetos? Uma se opõe ou complementa a outra?

Pode ter alguma relação, mas não precisa.

Não diria que há total oposição, mas são coisas diferentes, ainda que se assemelhem. De certo ponto de vista há complementariedade, mas em certo ponto começam ser bem diferentes e podem se opor de alguma maneira.

Obviamente que a **modelagem de dados** centram esforços, o pensamento em cima de... dados.

A **modelagem de objetos** centra esforços, o pensamento em cima de... objetos.

Objetos precisam de dados, certo? Então parece tudo a ver.

Porém, uma das escolas de OO diz que você deve se preocupar com os comportamentos, ou pelo menos os contratos deles. Deixam claro que o estado, os **dados são detalhes de implementação**. Pelo menos o jeito certo de fazer OO é assim. Então já dá para começar ver a oposição?

Aí vai aquilo que eu sempre falo, você não pode usar *getters/setters* porque isso expõe o detalhe de implementação, expõe o modelo de dados. De que adianta não expor o dado em si, isso nunca foi problema para o código, o que complica o código é o [vazamento da abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101), é expor o modelo de dados.

Mas é complicado fazer essa abstração toda, certo? É por isso que eu falo que por sorte as pessoas não programam orientado a objeto, elas apenas dizem que fazem isso. Que sorte, programar OO é muito difícil.

Quando o programador expõe o modelo de dados ele não está modelando objetos, está modelando dados. Que bom!

Por isso que eu falo que OOP funciona melhor para mecanismos, é aí que os dados são realmente meros detalhes de implementação. Quando você modela domínios você modela mais dados que qualquer outra coisa. O máximo que faz que tem cara de OO é que alguns comportamentos podem ou devem estar juntos (a maioria deve estar separado para não complicar a manutenção futura ([SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)), mas quando começa fazer isso está se afastando da ideia original de OO).

OOP puro é muito dogmático. Modelar dados é algo que as pessoas executam o tempo todo e faz mais sentido, ainda que em certo momento se use as duas técnicas de forma complementar. Então você vê por aí objetos com dados expostos, mesmo que através de *getters/setters*.

Conceitualmente se opõem, mas na prática se complementam porque as pessoas fazem um híbrido. Ainda bem!

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Existem outras técnicas de modelagem de dados além de DDD, dentro ou fora de moda? Pode falar um pouco a respeito? Seja relacionadas com OO como DDD ou não.

Comment: DDD não é para modelar dados, ela até ajuda nisso mas indiretamente, ela é uma técnica de coletar requisitos e expressar como a aplicação deve ser, o modelo de dados é só um ponto, e secundário, um dos motivos que não gosto muito disso. Tem várias outras formas que fazem algo semelhante, mas não diretamente a modelagem de dados.

Answer (score -2):

> O que é modelagem de dados (data modeling)?

Basicamente é desenhar a estrutura de tabelas do seu banco de dados. Pode ser feita através de ferramentas disponibilizadas pelas próprias empresas que desenvolvem os bancos de dados ou não.

Durante a modelagem de dados, você desenha suas tabelas, cria o relacionamento entre elas, defini índices, cria restrições, cria domínios de dados e muito mais.

Na grande maioria dos casos, a modelagem de dados é feita num desses programas específicos para isso. Isso acaba facilitando a vida de quem está trabalhando em um projeto, a gerar scripts para diversos bancos de dados. Além disso, é possível importar as tabelas de um banco de dados já existente.

Outra vantagem de utilizar um software de modelagem, é padronizar o nome de seus objetos. Isso evita o caos... Imagine 10 pessoas trabalhando em um mesmo projeto, cada um criando as coisas do seu jeito, no final, ninguém mais iria seguir um padrão, se não houve uma ferramenta que fizesse isso por eles.

> Em que contexto ela é utilizada?

Normalmente em sistemas comerciais, devolvidos por empresas de software. Mas não se restringe somente à isso. Qualquer um pode cria uma modelagem de dados para seu projetos, afim de apoia-lo durante o desenvolvimento do mesmo.

> Em que momento do desenvolvimento ela deve começar a ser feita?

Depende muito da metodologia usava no desenvolvimento.

Se for utilizado o famoso cascata, o analista de sistemas faz a modelagem dos dados antes de enviar uma especificação de trabalho para o programador.

Em casos onde utiliza-se a metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil, pode ser uma tarefa de uma `user story`.

> Tem relação com orientação a objetos? Uma se opõe ou complementa a outra?

Não necessariamente. A modelagem de dados é mais uma ferramenta que auxilia o desenvolvimento de um sistema. Você pode tela, mesmo em sistemas que não utilizam orientação a objeto. E não, uma não se opõe a outra.

Answer (score -3):

Fazer os diagramas de UML:

- Caso de Uso
- Diagrama de Classes
- Diagrama de Sequência
- Diagrama de Atividades

Para se ter uma boa visão do software.