# Existe aplicação prática em propriedades write-only?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, engenharia-de-software, propriedade, independente-de-linguagem

Na programação orientada a objetos, uma propriedade é um membro de uma classe que fornece informação sobre o objeto. Ou seja, propriedades expõem atributos.

Propriedades também podem ser "somente escrita". Um exemplo em C#:

```cs
public class Program
{
    string _foo;
    public string Foo
    {
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Embora a pergunta seja independente de linguagem, o mesmo é possível no Visual Basic, que ainda [expõe um açúcar sintático para tal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/writeonly), e em outras linguagens como Delphi.

Existe alguma aplicação prática em propriedades *write-only*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes leia isto: [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Isso indica que quer deixar o consumidor atribuir um valor para o objeto e depois não deixar ele mexer mais, então sempre que precisar disso pode ser usado.

Eu não gosto porque geralmente alguém esqueceu [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Mas C# tem incentivado um pouco isso em versões recentes usando [inicializador da propriedade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init). Não que isso tenha a ver com não ter a parte do *getter*, apenas estou mostrando que o construtor pode não ser tão usado quanto era antes, apesar de que alguns problemas podem surgir se a pessoa não souber usar. O construtor ainda dá mais garantias.

Pode existir alguns raros casos que a mudança precisa ser feita mesmo que o objeto já exista, mesmo que não seja só um inicializador.

## Aumento de segurança

A informação mais óbvia que eu penso é uma senha. Você tem motivos para mudar a senha, mas não tem motivos para pegar seu valor, inclusive porque se o objeto trata ela corretamente nem é possível mais pegar qual é a senha de fato porque algo foi criptografado.

Esse é um caso que o objeto usará o que está nele para autenticar alguma coisa mas esse uso é só interno (um método que fará a autenticação), não será visível. Impedir o acesso ao dado depois de entrado no objeto aumenta a segurança em vez de diminuir.

Mas esse caso precisa ser feito com cuidado porque envolve segurança, precisa ver se o objeto deve ficar mantendo uma senha circulando mesmo que criptografada.

E claro que vale para qualquer informação que não é armazenada igual ao que você mandou ou que não deva mais ser manipulada externamente.

Eu sempre falo, as pessoas não deveriam usar *getters/setters* automaticamente, tem que pensar quando isso é útil e quando deve só ter um método mais significativo para faça uma operação com mais sentido e nem saiba nada sobre o campo, até porque quase sempre a propriedade expõe o campo, então há algum nível de [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

Pode existir algum caso de objeto que deve ser imutável e que ele em si não tem porque pegar o valor (isso seria feito com um outro objeto que acabaria recebendo as informações desse primeiro objeto, ou seja, cada objeto tem uma função específica na aplicação). Eu acho complicação e zelo excessivo, mas é possível ter algo assim, é mais seguro para o programador ter um objeto só pra escrever e outro só para ler.

Eu não consigo pensar em algo prático, mas sempre que você precisar atribuir um mecanismo que passe ser detalhe de implementação do objeto e ninguém mais tema ver com isso então faz sentido, mas novamente, deveria ter feito no construtor.

Não dar acesso ao valor dentro do objeto é mais seguro nesses casos.

## Método só de escrita em vez de propriedade

Para que? Qual a vantagem disto? A propriedade já é um par de métodos e se não permitir a leitura tem um só, só não usará a sintaxe do método. Assim como ninguém sugere para usar sintaxe método quando só tem o *getter*, não faz sentido fazer isso quando só tem o *setter*. Já vi gente sugerindo isso, mas em geral as pessoas não sabem porque estão fazendo.

O motivo para usar sintaxe de método no lugar de propriedade é se ele tiver um processamento longo e não apenas acessar um estado de forma simples, ainda que não direta. Assim você sabe que está executando algo que exige processamento e te "obriga" ler a documentação para usar, enquanto que uma propriedade você tem em mente que é só acessar um dado simples.

Então se for uma propriedade de escrita que gera um processamento longo faz sentido o método, mas se for algo como uma senha a propriedade é adequada.

Precisamos sempre entender o motivo de certas regras. E que elas possuem exceções, programador bom é pragmático, não dogmático. Com a motivação pode-se tomar uma decisão adequada em vez de seguir cegamente o que alguém disse.

## Conclusão

De fato não tem tanta utilidade assim, mas a linguagem precisa suportar pros raros casos onde é útil, por isso que sempre digo que seguir cegamente receitas de bolo criadas por outras pessoas não é saber programar, "sempre" tem motivos para usar alguma coisa, mesmo que o normal seja não usar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

**Existe alguma aplicação prática em propriedades write-only?**

Sinceramente não consigo ver uma aplicação realmente prática. Se precisa setar algo em algum objeto e vai fazer isso uma única vez poderia usar um construtor.

Ou se quer setar um valor mais de uma vez e não quer ter acesso a esse conteúdo, poderia usar um método.

Apesar de ser possível fazer isso em `C#` como está no seu exemplo, existe até uma regra de *code analysis* que vai gerar um alerta (ou erro dependendo da configuração) sobre usar uma propriedade *write only*: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1044](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1044?view=vs-2019)

> CA1044: Properties should not be write only

Ou seja, "Propriedades não deveriam ser *write only*

A descrição do motivo dessa regra é:

> Get accessors provide read access to a property and set accessors provide write access. Although it is acceptable and often necessary to have a read-only property, **the design guidelines prohibit the use of write-only properties**. This is because letting a user set a value and then preventing the user from viewing the value does not provide any security. Also, without read access, the state of shared objects cannot be viewed, which limits their usefulness.

Em tradução livre:

> Acessadores Get fornecem acesso de leitura a uma propriedade e
> acessadores Set fornecem acesso de gravação. Embora seja aceitável e
> frequentemente necessário ter uma propriedade somente leitura, as
> **diretrizes de design proíbem o uso de propriedades somente gravação**.
> Isso ocorre porque permitir que um usuário defina um valor e, em
> seguida, impedir que o usuário visualize o valor não oferece nenhuma
> segurança. Além disso, **sem acesso de leitura, o estado dos objetos
> compartilhados não pode ser visualizado, o que limita sua utilidade**.

Estão algumas razões para evitar o uso de propriedades de só escrita. De qualquer forma, as regras de *code analysis* são opcionais e apenas um ponto para analisar.